# Как сделать класс, от которого нельзя наследоваться?

Tags: c++

Как сделать класс, от которого нельзя наследоваться?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class бесплодный final     {    };

class лжесын : public бесплодный    {    };
```

error C3246: "лжесын": нельзя наследовать из "бесплодный", так как было объявление в качестве "final"

Comment: в с++98/03 final был расширением gcc, в с++11 внесен в стандарт.

Comment: Альтернативы `final` для c++98/03 есть?

Comment: Нужно чтобы компилятор ошибку вывел?
Единственное что в голову приходит, это поместить конструктор в private.

Comment: @gecube Через `virtual inheritance` можно - см. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712992/how-to-define-sealed-class-in-c

Answer (score 2):

В С++ такая штука (final) не нужна
[раз](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/why-make-your-classes-final/) [два](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/topic/std-discussion/gdNTjaN3Ktw/discussion)

Comment: Поясните подробнее о чем речь.

Answer (score 2):

В С++2003 можно такой фокус применить

```
class Final {
  private:
    friend class A;
    Final() {}
};

class A : public virtual Final {
  public:
   A() {}   
};

class B: public A {
 }; // При попытке создать экземпляр класса B возникнет ошибка компиляции
```